# Excel 2016 line graph with data table and custom formatting of data used for the graph. Also date and data are reversed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Our office recently moved from Excel 2013 to 2016. We have existing graphs with data tables that no longer reflect the correct value formatting in the data table for certain users. But for some users, the same file appears correctly.

The data used for the graph is formatted as shown below. The graph and custom data format are also shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You will notice that the data for June 2017 is showing under July 2016. The date order has been reversed, but the data stays the same so the first date has the last data in it and *vice versa*.

It would be appreciated if someone could work out what needs to be changed to fix these two problems.

Comment: The Format Cells portion of the screenshot is almost unreadable.  I think the custom format is R # ###"k",[Red]# ###"k".  Please confirm or correct.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered problems recently with excel 2016 when running on computers that was clean installed with Windows 10 1703 + Office 2016.

The same excel sheet that worked fine on computers which was updated from Windows 10 1607 to 1703, Crashed when saved on Computers that was clean installed with Windows 10 1703 + Office 2016.

After hunting for a solution for some days i found this: 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/bug-report-excel-no-longer-can-handle-charts/a58c97b1-1c37-4222-ad81-bb8d11d41c2f

Which led me to that maybe it was a location/region issue, so i went to Control Panel / Region, and changed the Format from "English (Denmark)" to "Danish (Denmark)". And just like that, all the problems went away.  the excel sheet was just as fast on the Clean installed computer, as it was on the updated computer. and i could save it without issues.

**Solution:**
 Check that your location and format is setup correctly in Control Panel / Region. Or at least set it up like on the computers where it works correctly.